# How to to read input stream from Magnetic stripe reader with keyboard support in Windows 10 universal app

Tags: usb, windows-10, win-universal-app

We have tried the approach suggested at:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn312121(v=vs.85).aspx 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn303343(v=vs.85).aspx

We are able to find out list of all the magneticDevices using below code snippet

```cs
var magneticDevices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(aqsFilter);
```

but we are not able to get HidDevice object from the below code. It is giving null.

```cs
HidDevice device = await HidDevice.FromIdAsync(magneticDevices[0].Id
```

We have also set device capabilities in the app manifest file like below.

```xml
<DeviceCapability Name="humaninterfacedevice">
    <Device Id="vidpid:0ACD 0520">
      <Function Type="usage:0001 0006"/>
    </Device>
</DeviceCapability>

<DeviceCapability Name="usb">
    <Device Id="vidpid:0ACD 0520">
      <Function Type="winUsbId:4d1e55b2-f16f-11cf-88cb-001111000030"/>
    </Device>
</DeviceCapability>
```

Code for the complete Function

```cs
 private async Task<bool> HasCardReader()
        {
            bool hasCardReader = false;
            ushort usagePage = 0x0001;
            ushort usageId = 0x0006;
            ushort vendorId = 0x0ACD;
            ushort productId = 0x0520;
            var aqsFilter = HidDevice.GetDeviceSelector(usagePage, usageId, vendorId, productId);
            var magneticDevices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(aqsFilter);
            try
            {
                if (magneticDevices != null && magneticDevices.Count > 0)
                {
                    HidDevice device = await HidDevice.FromIdAsync(magneticDevices[0].Id, Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
                    inputReportEventHandler = new TypedEventHandler<HidDevice, HidInputReportReceivedEventArgs>(this.OnInputReportEvent);
                    device.InputReportReceived += inputReportEventHandler;
                    var watcher = DeviceInformation.CreateWatcher(aqsFilter);
                    watcher.Added += WatcherAdded;
                    watcher.Removed += WatcherRemoved;
                    watcher.Start();
                    hasCardReader = true;
            }
                else
                {

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logging.LoggingSessionScenario.LogMessageAsync(ex.Message, LoggingLevel.Error);
            }
            return hasCardReader;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons for the null return value, but I don't think there is something wrong with your code, since you can find the device by calling FindAllAsync. I will suggest you to troubleshoot this issue using [this official HIDDevice sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/93bdfb92b3da76f2e49c959807fc5643bf0940c9/Samples/CustomHidDeviceAccess) on GitHub.

I successfully connected to my external hid device with that sample by changing the vid & pid & usagepage & usageid to my device.

In EventHandlerForDevice.cs, find the function OpenDeviceAsync, and you will notice the following possible reasons when null is returned by FromIdAsync.

```
else
{
    successfullyOpenedDevice = false;

    notificationStatus = NotifyType.ErrorMessage;

    var deviceAccessStatus = DeviceAccessInformation.CreateFromId(deviceInfo.Id).CurrentStatus;

    if (deviceAccessStatus == DeviceAccessStatus.DeniedByUser)
    {
        notificationMessage = "Access to the device was blocked by the user : " + deviceInfo.Id;
    }
    else if (deviceAccessStatus == DeviceAccessStatus.DeniedBySystem)
    {
        // This status is most likely caused by app permissions (did not declare the device in the app's package.appxmanifest)
        // This status does not cover the case where the device is already opened by another app.
        notificationMessage = "Access to the device was blocked by the system : " + deviceInfo.Id;
    }
    else
    {
        // Most likely the device is opened by another app, but cannot be sure
        notificationMessage = "Unknown error, possibly opened by another app : " + deviceInfo.Id;
    }
}
```

Have a try with that sample(**Scenario1**) and change the ids in both appxmanifest and SampleConfiguration.cs(class Device). If you cannot see your device in the device list, that means the configuration is incorrect for your device.